# why end call button dosent work in android

Tags: android

I used action call in my activity to call my telephone.The action call works correctly but when I press end call button in my cellphone, the call ends in it but the telephone keeps ringing. what is the solution?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                String phone = "tel:" + "--------";
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(phone));
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "keeps ringing"? Which telephone keeps ringing?

Comment: @AntonSavin the telephone which I call it in my activity by action call.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware-related issue with your spesific phone

Comment: @gilonm incredibly your solution worked for me,thanks alot.

Comment: @h3diyeh I'm saying this because I have done this successfully with my phone, therefor I presume it is a problem with yours, no hard feelings!